# Introduction in ARM A7 MMU

Tags: arm, mmu

I'm trying to understand the ARMv7 MMU of the BCM2836 (Raspberry PI 2).

For starting points I already consulted the ARM ARM & TRM.

But somehow it's too much information there and thats confusing.

Does anyone knows any good tutorial about the MMU.

In particular I want to map the lowest 1MB virtual adresses (0x0 - 0x100000) to the highest 1MB physical addresses (0xFFF00000 - 0xFFFFFFFF).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There are the questions tagged [arm+mmu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm+mmu).  There are many choices with the ARM MMU structure.  Sections support 1MB areas, so for you case you can just use one level of an MMU.  Stackoverflow is not for tutorials.  Did you try to find anything on the internet?

Comment: what are you thinking is addressable from the arm at that 0xFFF00000 to 0xFFFFFFFF physical range?